# "Big" integers in Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, emscripten

I'm playing with Emscripten and compiling some simple programs to test out how well it performs. Here's a `fib(n)` algorithm that I quickly put together. Implementation isn't important, but here's the source if you need it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define KEY_TYPE unsigned int
#define VALUE_TYPE unsigned long long

// Simple linked list implementation
typedef struct list{
    KEY_TYPE key;
    VALUE_TYPE value;
    struct list* next;
} list;

void free_list(list** headPtr){
    list* head = *headPtr;
    while(head){
        list* next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = next;
    }
}

VALUE_TYPE lookup_list(list** headPtr, KEY_TYPE key){
    for(list* head = *headPtr; head; head = head->next){
        if(head->key == key){
            return head->value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void add_list(list** headPtr, list* block){
    block->next = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = block;
}

VALUE_TYPE fib_recur(list** lookup, KEY_TYPE n){
    VALUE_TYPE value;
    // base cases
    if(n < 2)   return n;

    // look for cached answer
    value = lookup_list(lookup, n);
    if(value > 0)   return value;

    // calculate answer
    value = fib_recur(lookup, n - 1) + fib_recur(lookup, n - 2);

    list* head = calloc(sizeof(list), 1);
    head->key = n;
    head->value = value;
    add_list(lookup, head);

    return value;
}


VALUE_TYPE fib(n){
    list* listPtr = NULL;
    VALUE_TYPE num = fib_recur(&listPtr, n);
    free_list(&listPtr);
    return num;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2)   return 1;

    KEY_TYPE key;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &key); 
    VALUE_TYPE value = fib(key);
    printf("fib(%d) = %lld\n", key, value);
    return 0;
}
```

The actual implementation in C is correct (tested by compiling with clang.) In Node.js it worked well for small integers, however when I try 47, `fib(47)` returned -1323752223 which isn't correct.

```
var Module = require("./fib.js");
var fib = Module.cwrap("fib", "number", ["number"]);

for(var i = 1; i <= 90; i++){
    console.log(i, fib(i));
}
```

```
45 1134903170
46 1836311903
47 -1323752223  <-- overflow?
48 512559680    <-- all numbers are incorrect after this point
49 -811192543
```

Why is that? The command I used to compile the C code is the following:

```bash
emcc fib.c -O1 -o fib.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_fib']"
```

Comment: emscripten-1.37.1 and emscripten-1.35.0 looks like no overflow.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in JS you have all numbers expressed as `double`s and integers in Asm.js subset are emulated using them. But 64 bit int cannot be expressed in `double`, so from what I remember, in Emscripten calling convention the highest 32 bits of `long long` is returned using some global temporary variable.

Compile your program with debug information (the `-g3` compiler option) (you may have to try different optimization levels: on `-O0` the generated code may be too noisy, but on `-O3` it may be not easy to understand) and inspect your `main` function for how your `_fib` is called and **how the return value is acquired**. But I fear, this calling convention may change in future Emscripten versions. Meanwhile, you can try to read the documentation on Emscripten's `val.h` and `bind.h`, but I have never used them myself.